# Aggregate Subgroup values based on condition Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Aggregate Subgroup values based on condition - if All values in subgroup are same then take max, if any of the values is different then sum.
ex: Data

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: No images, please. Reproducing your dataframe from an image becomes very tedious. Instead copy-paste your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_apply` and a logical condition to get `sum` or `max` values:

```
>>> df.groupby(['index', 'columns'], as_index=False)['values'] \
      .apply(lambda x: x.sum() if len(set(x)) != 1 else x.max())[df.columns]

   index  values columns
0      1      80       A
1      1      13       B
2      2      30       A
3      2      20       B
```